# Listening to account changes for multiple accounts on Solana

Tags: web3.js, rpc, subscription

I'm trying to use the Solana RPC to listen to incoming transactions on multiple accounts at once. [The logsSubscribe documentation](https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#logssubscribe) states that an object with an array of *Pubkeys (as base-58 encoded strings)* can be set as filter. I have tried this but whenever using an array with more than one public key, it gives the error `'Invalid Request: Only 1 address supported'`. The error seems to be obvious, but reading the documentation you should be able to use multiple public keys.

If there's no way to listen to account changes for multiple accounts using `logsSubscribe` then is there a different method?

The RPC request:

```
    let subscription = JSON.stringify({
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "logsSubscribe",
        "params": [{
            "mentions": ["addressOne", "addressTwo"]
        }, {
            "commitment": "finalized"
        }]
    })

    socket.send(subscription);
```

The output:

```
{
  jsonrpc: '2.0',
  error: {
    code: -32602,
    message: 'Invalid Request: Only 1 address supported'
  },
  id: 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen to multiple accounts, you'll have to do it through multiple different subscriptions, since RPC only supports one at a time currently. The interface was likely written to be as generic as possible, but was only wired up to manage one key per request.

Note that `logsSubscribe` isn't listening to changes to accounts, just mentions of the account. If you want to listen to changes, you'll need to use `accountSubscribe`.

Either way, the documentation should probably be updated to specify that only one pubkey is supported in `logsSubscribe`.