# Listening to incoming transactions / account changes for multiple accounts

Tags: web3.js, transactions, subscription

I am trying to listen to multiple account changes, or incoming transactions for an array of addresses. The `logsSubscribe` method should work, but gives [this error](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6300/listening-to-account-changes-for-multiple-accounts-on-solana). In what other way can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listening to account changes for multiple accounts on Solana](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6300/listening-to-account-changes-for-multiple-accounts-on-solana)